# initComponents(); condition fail?

Tags: java, swing, initialization, components

I have a problem.

When I click on the "Blue Theme" button, the jFrame1 passes a text for a jTextField the jFrame2. But.... when the jFrame2 open, AUTOMATICALLY the theme must change. For this I made a simple condition in

```
initComponents();
```

jTextField receive the text without problems, but the theme doesn't change.
Here's my code

```
public Frame2() {
    initComponents();
    if("Blue".equals(ReceiveColor.getText())){
        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }else{

    }
}
```

Any idea on how to solve that problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you're inspecting the state of the variable within the constructor, but the constructor takes no parameters, how is it possible for the state to be equal to that of the first frame?  You might also like to take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Is it impossible to do? LOL

Comment: No, but you need to pass the value to `Frame2` via the constructor

Comment: And how can I do this bro? Sorry, I'm newbie :D

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)